# Update record with count as a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need to update duplicated records as a invalid, but keep only record.

my table structure is as follows:

**field Name**

```
id (primary key)
phoneNo
IsValid
```

Sample data is as follows:

```
id       |  phoneNo     | IsValid          
--------------------------------------
1        |  011         |    1
2        |  011         |    1
3        |  022         |    1
4        |  022         |    1
5        |  033         |    1
6        |  011         |    1
```

my **output** should be something like this :

Sample data is as follows:

```
id       |  phoneNo     | IsValid          
--------------------------------------
1        |  011         |    0
2        |  011         |    0
3        |  022         |    0
4        |  022         |    1
5        |  033         |    1
6        |  011         |    1
```

either minimum id or maximum id is NOT a problem. only condition is **one** row should be there as valid row.

what i tried so far:

```
update phone set IsValid=0 where id in
 (select id  from phone
    where id not in (
       select MAX(id)id
       from phone 
       group by phoneNo
      having COUNT(phoneNo)>1))
and IsValid=1
```

in this case my o/p as follows:

```
id       |  phoneNo     | IsValid          
--------------------------------------
1        |  011         |    0
2        |  011         |    0
3        |  022         |    0
4        |  022         |    1
5        |  033         |    0
6        |  011         |    1
```

in here this **033** record also marked as o, How can i solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove having clause from your query there is no need of it and try...

```
    update phone set IsValid=0 where id in
    (select id  from phone
    where id not in (
    select MAX(id)id
    from phone 
    group by phoneNo))
    and IsValid=1
```

Answer (score 1):

try this query:

```
UPDATE phone t1 SET IsValid = 0 WHERE
t1.ID NOT in (SELECT MAX(t2.ID) FROM phone t2 GROUP BY t2.PHONENO);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming TAB as your table name:

```
UPDATE  TAB
SET     TAB.ISVALID = 0
WHERE   TAB.ID NOT IN(SELECT MAX(ID) ID FROM TAB GROUP BY PHONENO)
```

Answer (score 1):

Its just above answer but with complete code.

```
CREATE TABLE Sample1 (
id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
,phoneNo INT
,IsValid BIT)
GO

INSERT INTO Sample1 VALUES(011,1)
INSERT INTO Sample1 VALUES(011,1)
INSERT INTO Sample1 VALUES(022,1)
INSERT INTO Sample1 VALUES(022,1)
INSERT INTO Sample1 VALUES(033,1)
INSERT INTO Sample1 VALUES(011,1)

SELECT* FROM Sample1
GO

UPDATE Sample1 SET IsValid=0 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Sample1 GROUP BY phoneNo)
GO

DROP TABLE Sample1
GO
```